# How to import Excel file in Intelli J for Python?

Tags: python

Is there a built-in function to browse & import Excel files for Python in **Intelli J** in Windows (like 'Reveal in Finder' in MAC), or we need to do it manually via providing path of files within the code body like before :
`path = r"C:\Users\ayazk\Desktop\Python\Demo_Excel\Test_file.xlsx"`

while doing via path, i get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DEFUSEDXML' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ayazk\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\__init__.py)
```